# Xalan 2.7.1 Issues

Tags: centos, solaris, xalan

We were using the Xalan 2.7.1 in our Java application which was deployed in Solaris with JDK 1.7, 32 bit. The XSL were also compiled in JDK 1.7, 32 bit.
We are parsing our XML and using the node() function in some conditions like below:
[descendant::node() != '']

But we recently moved our application to CentOS with JDK 1.8 64 bit. The XSL were compiled in JDK 1.8, 64 bit. After this migration/upgrade in production , we are now having issues with the above condition (yes, we missed to test this corner scenario in QA environment) . The above condition is always returning false.

And due to this, our XML is not getting properly parsed.
Do we know if this feature is OS/JDK dependent.
Any pointers will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Can you run your process on Solaris under a 64-bit JDK 1.8?

Comment: I am not sure if we will be able to run in Solaris 64 bit as these were were already end of life and no further deployment is available in these boxes.  Has anyone else faced this kind of issue in migration.

Comment: That would have to be a **REALLY** old version of Solaris to fail to support 64-bit executables.